# Do 3 unified checks

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, upload

I have a form with 3 file input fields, but Laravel is giving me this problem: [link](https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/failed-to-return-error-message-validatepostsizephp)

So, I will check before sending the files, the maximum resolution will be 2000x2000, I got this code and modified, but it is still giving an error because one passes the other. I want to know how I can unify the 3 checks into one.

Here's my code:

```
$("#personal").change(function() { 
  var fr = new FileReader;
  fr.onload = function() {
    var imgPersonal = new Image;
    imgPersonal.onload = function() {
      if (imgPersonal.width > 2000 &&  this.height > 2000) {
        $("#submitDocs").attr("disabled", true); 
      } else {
        $("#submitDocs").removeAttr("disabled");
      }
    };
    imgPersonal.src = fr.result;
  };
  fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});

$("#self").change(function() { 
  var fr = new FileReader;
  fr.onload = function() {
    var imgSelf = new Image;
    imgPersonal.onload = function() {
      if (imgSelf.width > 2000 &&  this.height > 2000) {
        $("#submitDocs").attr("disabled", true);
      } else {
          $("#submitDocs").removeAttr("disabled");
        }
      }
    };
    imgSelf.src = fr.result;
  };
  fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});

$("#address").change(function() { 
  var fr = new FileReader;
  fr.onload = function() {
    var imgAddress = new Image;
    imgPersonal.onload = function() {
      if (imgAddress.width > 2000 &&  this.height > 2000) {
        $("#submitDocs").attr("disabled", true); 
      } else {
          $("#submitDocs").removeAttr("disabled");
        } 
      }
    };
    imgAddress.src = fr.result;
  };
  fr.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
});
```

Comment: Your code has some syntax errors - brackets/parentheses don't match up everywhere. Also, when invoking a constructor, use parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting all the duplicate code in a single function, in keeping with [DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and keeping a persistent object that checks to see if any of the uploaded images are invalid:

```
const checks = {
  personal: true,
  self: true,
  address: true,
};

function validate(file, checkAttr) {
  const fr = new FileReader();
  fr.readAsDataURL(file);
  fr.onload = function() {
    const img = new Image();
    img.onload = () => {
      if (img.width > 2000 || img.height > 2000) checks[checkAttr] = true;
      else checks[checkAttr] = false;
      if (checks.personal && checks.self && checks.address) $("#submitDocs").removeAttr("disabled");
      else $("#submitDocs").attr("disabled", true);
    }
    img.src = fr.result;
  }
}

$("#personal").change(function() {
  validate(this.files[0], 'personal');
});

// other handlers
```

Answer (score 0):

@CertainPerformance, Thanks, I was able to do it your way, I did this function and I used onblur = "btndisabled();" in each input

```
function btndisabled() {
        var sizePersonal = personal.files[0].size;
        var sizeSelf = self.files[0].size;
        var sizeAddress = address.files[0].size;
        if (sizePersonal < 1000000 && sizeSelf < 1000000 && sizeAddress < 1000000) {
          $("#submitDocs").removeAttr("disabled");
        } else {
          alert('File larger than 1MB');
          $("#submitDocs").attr("disabled", true);
        }
      }
```